# VBA Textbox loses focus on 'Alt-Gr'

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I am experiencing a funny behaviour of Textboxes on a VBA Userform: On pressing Alt-Gr the box loses focus. This happens after running a bit of VBA initialization code for the form. The text box has neither initialization code nor event listeners. Starting the user form straight out of the IDE everything is fine.

I suspect a MS Office or Windows update to be responsible for this change in behaviour but I can't pin it down.

Anyone with an idea what the problem is and how to fix that? Thanks for any suggestions.

BTW: The VBA runs within a CRM Application called Organice, which has an embedded VBA runtime environment.

stengbiegel

Comment: I would start with trying it on another (a clean) machine to cross-check that it's not some third-party process that grabs focus on ALT-GR.

Comment: Well, that is a good idea. Unfortunately we have observed this behaviour on a handful of machines. But I will talk to the administrator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone. Still no idea what it was.